# Returning results from MySQL as a multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have to store tree like data structure in MySQL table. Any node can have any number of children and depth of tree is not fixed. I have created a table with a column of parent node so that I can traverse the tree.
I need to fetch the whole tree rooted at a given node from table and render it in php page. I can make a procedure to return all children of a given parent and render it. But for that I have to fire a query recursively for each node.
 I want to return the whole tree structure rooted at a given node in single query. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Could you include the description of relevant tables you have there please?

Comment: I have just one table. Each row has description of a node and a link to parent node. Root node has null as parent node. Is there any better way to represent ? Thanks

Comment: You need to post the code you've tried and state a specific question about where you're stuck. This sounds like you're just reading off a homework assignment and asking someone to do it for you.

Comment: I am not stuck anywhere.I can fetch the tree using recursion but  I don't want to use recursion due to performance penalties as tree has no upper limit on depth or number of children, so I was asking if there is any way to structure the data so that I can get the whole tree in single query from database.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is 'ways of storing hierarchical data' in relational databases.

If you want to avoid recursion you will have to duplicate a bit of data in form of extra column or table holding ancestor/descendant information.

Have a look at following URL describing few ways of doing this: http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am going through it.